# Disabling Bootstrap Submit Buttons with multiple Forms on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that contains three tabs with a `form` and `submit` on each tab.   Before I enable the `submit buttons` I would like to perform some date validation.   Now an option is to just redirect the submit buttons to a `formSubmit()` function, however I was wondering if there is an easier way of identifying the submit buttons associated with a form id.

At the moment I use:

```
$(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

Which works for the first button but not the other tabs.  I have tried indexing , i.e.

```
$($(':input[type="submit"]')[index].prop('disabled', false);
```

and that does not appear to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just add a class to the buttons you want to disable and do it all at once?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I could do that because only one tab is visible at anyone time but then I would have to revalidate each tab as the user clicked on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I used to disable the buttons on my website

```
$("#formTheButtonIsIn :button").attr("disabled", false);
```

Comment: Thankyou.  That works.  Btw,  I don't understand why someone voted your answer down but it works perfectly.   I have tried with both the attr and prop methods and both worked fine.